# a que se debe este kernel base error?

Tags: vb.net, windows

Hola obtengo el siguiente kernel base error:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: vbc.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.30729.5420
  Application Timestamp:    5a6fcdb8
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17932
  Fault Module Timestamp:   503275ba
  Exception Code:   e0434f4d
  Exception Offset: 0000d3cf
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    3082

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Alguien podria ayudarme o explicarme a que se debe este error?

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!